# How to use SOCKS proxy or HTTP proxy with Sockets in Java?

Tags: java, http, sockets, proxy, socks

I am running a `ServerSocket` on localhost at port 1436. I can not connect the client's `Socket` through a valid free `SOCKS` proxy server or `HTTP` proxy server.

```
        String proxyHost = "68.71.247.130" ,serverName = "localhost";
        int proxyPort = 4145, serverPort = 1436;

        System.setProperty("socksProxyHost", proxyHost);
        System.setProperty("socksProxyPort", String.valueOf(proxyPort));
        System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");

        SocketAddress proxyAddr = new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort);
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, proxyAddr);
        try(Socket socket =new Socket(proxy);){
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(serverName, serverPort) );
            socket.setSoTimeout(0);
            System.out.println("Connected through proxy server = " + proxyHost + " at port = " + proxyPort);
        }
```

It gives the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: SOCKS: Network unreachable
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:487)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:583)
    at test/proxy.Main.main(Main.java:27)
```

I have also tried the above code with `HTTP` and its right `System` properties,

```
        String serverName = "localhost", proxyHost = "46.101.160.223";
        int serverPort = 1436, proxyPort = 80;

        System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", proxyHost);
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", String.valueOf(proxyPort));
```

```
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, proxyAddr);
```

But it is also giving me an error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:178)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:498)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(HttpClient.java:557)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(HttpClient.java:555)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.privilegedOpenServer(HttpClient.java:554)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:598)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:246)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:351)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:373)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1309)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1287)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1128)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1057)
    at java.base/java.net.HttpConnectSocketImpl.doTunnel(HttpConnectSocketImpl.java:194)
    at java.base/java.net.HttpConnectSocketImpl$2.run(HttpConnectSocketImpl.java:175)
    at java.base/java.net.HttpConnectSocketImpl$2.run(HttpConnectSocketImpl.java:173)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
    at java.base/java.net.HttpConnectSocketImpl.privilegedDoTunnel(HttpConnectSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.base/java.net.HttpConnectSocketImpl.connect(HttpConnectSocketImpl.java:119)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:583)
    at test/proxy.Main.main(Main.java:27)
```

Comment: Is the proxy address and port correct?

Comment: I got the proxy address and port from the website.

https://spys.one/free-proxy-list/US/

Answer (score 0):

In the first case your computer is connecting to a SOCKS proxy server and then asking the SOCKS proxy server to connect to localhost. Think about that for a moment: when the SOCKS proxy server connects to localhost, it connects to itself.

The SOCKS proxy server won't let you do that, presumably because it's a security vulnerability for the server. Some services only allow connection from localhost as a security measure; if the proxy server would let you connect to its localhost, it would bypass that and let you connect to services on the proxy server.

In the second case it seems that you got the proxy address or port wrong as your computer was not able to connect to the proxy server.

Comment: How can I tell the `SOCKS` proxy server to connect to `SocketServer` running on my machine? My IP4 address is 192.168.1.247

Comment: @MuhammadShah because the proxy server is on the Internet, you would have to use port forwarding to make sure people on the Internet can connect to your server.